# Set an alias on Bourne shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, alias

I am using a scrtipt with instruction 'SH -c command', where command is an alias from bash, this alias can not be interpreted into Bourne shell. ¿Do you have any idea for set this alias into Bourne shell and getting that it works in the new shell? Thanks everyone !

Comment: The new shell does not have an alias defined in the current shell, otherwise aliases would make things extremely confusing.  Aliases are meant for interactive use not for scripting.  Make a procedure instead of an alias, call it to produce the desired command (without aliases) and only then pass to a second shell.

Comment: As a minor thing, commands in Unix-like systems are usually case-sensitive, so you're likely not running `SH`, but `sh`.

Answer (score 4):

I would be surprised if it's a real Bourne shell you have on Linux. Though the Bourne shell has now been ported to Linux, it's generally not installed or even packaged by default.

You'd only install it for archaeology purposes.

Maybe you're confusing `sh` (which nowadays refers to an interpreter or another of the POSIX `sh` language) with the Bourne shell (an ancient shell that also used to be called `sh` (and from which modern `sh`s descend, but also differ)).

The Bourne shell didn't have aliases. Modern `sh` do.

Aliases however are local to the current shell. If you execute a new shell (whether it's `bash`, `sh`, `csh`, `zsh`...), that new shell will not inherit those aliases.

You'd need to redefine those aliases in the new shell.

`bash` has a way to dump the definition of one of its alias in a syntax that is compatible with that of `sh`. So you could do:

```
alias foo='echo foo' # alias defined in bash
foo_definition=$(alias foo)
sh -c "$foo_definition
foo"
```

Or simply:

```
sh -c "$(alias foo)
foo"
```

Now, there's a catch in that it doesn't work in all implementations of `sh`. First you'll noticed we didn't do:

```
sh -c "$(alias foo);foo"
```

Which would have worked in *no* `sh` implementation.

That's because aliases are really like some form of macro expansion. Because alias expansion is done prior to parsing, in `alias foo='echo foo'; foo`, by the time the `alias` command is run, the line has already been parsed.

Putting the alias definition on one line and its usage on the next works around that for some shells, but some others (like `yash` or `zsh`) parse the whole `sh -c` code as a whole, so alias expansion won't work there.

However because aliases are more or less macros, that is the substitution of some text with some other text, you might as well do the substitution by hand.

You can get the value of an alias by doing:

```
eval "$(alias foo | sed '1s/ /_/')"
```

Which would store the definition of the `foo` alias into the `$alias_foo` variable.

Then, you can do:

```
sh -c "$alias_foo"
```

To have the value of the `foo` alias passed as shell code to `sh`.

You may prefer using functions than aliases for that purpose. Like for aliases, functions are local to the current shell. Some shells like `rc` or `bash` can export functions to other invocations of the same interpreter.

```
foo() { echo foo; }
export -f foo
sh -c foo
```

Would only work on systems where `sh` is implemented with `bash` (mostly only Apple OS/X and some Linux-based systems).

A more portable approach would be like for aliases to dump the definition of the function into the code passed to `sh -c`:

```
sh -c "$(typeset -f foo); foo"
```

This time, no problem with time-of-expansion, time-of-parsing as functions as opposed to aliases as functions are real structures of the language.

However, you need to make sure the definition of the function contains code that is valid `sh` syntax and doesn't use any `bash` extension.

Comment: I definitely, I referred to the modern sh shell, your response has give me many posible solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about Bash in particular-

That happens because when Bash is given a command using `-c`, it starts in non-interactive mode, and in particular, alias expansion is disabled.

In general, you shouldn't use aliases in scripts, but instead you should use shell functions or other scripts. If you *really* want to use aliases, try `bash -ic <alias_command>`. The `-i` will start the shell in interactive mode, read your configuration files such as `/.bashrc`, then alias expansion will be enabled.

Note- Aliases that Bash sees will come from the configuration files, not from the parent shell.

Comment: Alias expansion is done in `sh -c`. It's only in `bash` (when not called as `sh`) that aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive.

Comment: `<shell> -ic <alias_command>` will not cause the aliases to be magically passed to the new `<shell>`. However, with some shells, that will cause the `~/.bashrc`/`.zshrc` to be sourced and then the alias definitions in there being loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I edited to talk about `bash` only.