# setting alias for sourcing a script, to run that script in jenkins with restricted permissions

Tags: scripting, alias, jenkins

I want to run `source ./script_name` instead of `./script_name`. Can I create an alias for this ?

The Jenkins job will run the script as `./script_name` and I can't edit the way it will run the script on the server. I need to run this script as a source so as to run the commands in the same shell. So whenever the Jenkins runs `./my_script` it will in turn run `source ./my_script` instead.

Comment: the  given links don't answer specific to this problem.

Comment: What is the problem? you want to run a script over an alias or not?

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to create alias with ./ thing.

Comment: because the Jenkins is calling like this only and I can't edit it to call the script the other way.

Comment: can you edit the question and add more details? what's with this : `alias script_name="source /home/user/./script_name"` in your bashrc ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276351/how-can-i-execute-shell-script-in-jenkinsfile

Comment: It should be like alias ./script_name="source /home/user/./script_name" only.

Comment: No, you can't, sorry.  Instead, please clarify why you need this. If you are using Jenkins to run scripts and commands, then include this in the question along with what issue it is that you are trying to solve.  Note that creating an alias is not the issue you are trying to solve, it's a solution that you think solves an issue that you haven't mentioned, and that I think you have misunderstood.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity and grammar.  If it changed the intent of the question, then please cancel it.

Comment: @RonJohn edited the question

Comment: What does "restricted permissions" have to do with anything at all? **No**, you cannot -- full stop impossible -- make a shell you can't configure retroactively decide to source your script instead of run it, if the only thing you can configure is the text of that script, because by the time the script is running _it was already forked into a subprocess_. But the statement above is making a bunch of caveats the question currently doesn't support; you don't say anything about whether "if the only thing you can configure is the text of the script" is true, f/e.

Comment: There may be some moral equivalent way to accomplish your larger goal, but if you don't tell us that larger goal then we can't help you, and we're going to be over here being very annoyed that you're not helping us help you by describing the details of which restrictions you do and don't have and what the surrounding context is.

Comment: (For example, in a lot of circumstances it might be possible to make the sourced-vs-executed question completely moot by having the forked-off subprocess take over whatever work was previously going to be done later in the sourced script so the work is instead done in the forked-off subprocess; but we need to know details to work out whether _your circumstances in particular_ fall into that category).

Answer (score 3):

You have a **bash script** in `/home/user/` and the **bash script** is `myscript` you can set an alias to run

`/home/user/myscript`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "WELCOME BASH"
```

Run `chmod +x /home/user/myscript`

1. create an `alias` and execute by alias name

   - Temporary `alias` — run this in the terminal

     `alias myscript="/home/user/myscript"`
   - Permanent `alias` in `~/.bashrc` (/home/user/.bashrc) — add/edit this to your `.bashrc` file

     `alias myscript="/home/user/myscript"`

   Now run in terminal: `myscript`

**Option 1**

Add this to your bashrc:

`alias myscript="source /home/user/./myscript"`
or
`alias my_script="source ./my_script"`

Run `my_script`, to run `source ./my_script`

This work only for your user account. If you want the alias for all users, you will need to add the alias to the system-wide shell configuration file `/etc/bash.bashrc` for `bash` or ask the administrator to add it.

**Option 2**

Login to your jenkins server and navigate to the job configuration page for the job you want to use the source command

In build section of the job configuration, add a new build step of type **Execute shell**

In **Command** field, define a function that wraps the source command

Example:

```
function my_source() {
    source ./home/user/my_script
    # or
    source /home/user/./myscript
    # or
    source /home/user/myscript
}
```

Assign this function to an alias temporary or permanent
`alias my_alias='my_source'`

**Option 3**

Create a wrapper script

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/my_script
```

Make the file executable

`chmod +x my_script`

now you can run `./my_script`

Check if the script is located in the same directory as the original script, or in directory that is included in your system PATH variable

**Option 4**

when the Jenkins job tries to run `./my_script`, it will actually run `source ./my_script` with this.

Create a symbolic link to your script:
`ln -s $(realpath my_script) source`

When Jenkins job run `./my_script`, it will run `source ./my_script` from the symbolic link you created

**Use this with caution**, clean up the symbolic link after you done the job with

`rm source`

**Sources**:

- [Jenkins Permissions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/access-control/permissions/)
- [How can I execute Shell script in Jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276351/how-can-i-execute-shell-script-in-jenkinsfile)
- [What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it)
- [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file)
- [Revisiting Bash vs Source difference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096236/revisiting-bash-vs-source-difference)
- [Source vs . why different behaviour?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/source-vs-why-different-behaviour)
- [Set an alias on Bourne shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302807/set-an-alias-on-bourne-shell)
- [How to Create Bash Aliases](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/)

Comment: @AnubhavRai  Can you add some more details why you can't edit the server or what are your restrictions, because i am using jenkins too in a docker container and i got not problems to create and execute jobs with script or other ...

Comment: I don't have permissions to do that.